# Why Mollweide projection of a map in Julia Healpix give NAN error?

Tags: julia

In Julia I am trying to generate a Mollweide projection of a map in Healpix using the following lines

```
using Healpix
using Plots
gr()  

nside = 8
m = Map{Float64, RingOrder}(nside)
m.pixels[:] = 1:length(m.pixels)
mollweide(m)
```

I am encountering the following error:

```
(Float32[NaN NaN … NaN NaN; NaN NaN … NaN NaN; … ; NaN NaN … NaN NaN; NaN NaN … NaN NaN], Bool[0 0 … 0 0; 0 0 … 0 0; … ; 0 0 … 0 0; 0 0 … 0 0], false)
```

Please help.

Comment: I don't know exactly about the types in question, but contrary to NumPy arrays, indexing with `:` in Julia creates a copy, not a view. And in fact assignment to it should have failed. Don't you get an error in that line?

Answer (score 0):

sorry for the delay, I have just found your question.

It seems you copied the example in the [documentation](https://ziotom78.github.io/Healpix.jl/stable/visualization/) but mistyped the last line: it should be `plot(m)`, not `mollweide(m)` like it is in HealPy (`mollweide(m)` returns the 2D bitmap of the map).

Note that in Healpix 3.0 the name `Map` has been renamed to `HealpixMap`.